# Why is it that most mathematical statements that mathematicians tend to study are decidable?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

This is a bit of a philosophical question. Due to Godel, we know that there are undecidable statements in ZFC set theory. But why is it that most statements that mathematicians tend to study in practice are decidable? Is it something to do with the fact that "humanly interesting" mathematical statements are special in some way? To put the question another way, why is it so hard to find "natural" examples of undecidable statements? To date, I don't think anyone has found a natural undecidable statement about finitary objects that everyone recognizes to be undecidable. Anyway, I would love to read some text on this topic.

Comment: There are classical statements about arithmetic objects that are known to be unprovable (either way) in first-order Peano arithmetic but true in $\mathbb{N}$ with the axioms of full set theory: I’m thinking of Goodstein and Paris-Harrington.

Comment: Is it meaningful to call a single statement decidable? My understanding is that only a set of statements can be called decidable, based on whether there is a decision procedure for membership in said set.

Comment: @Mark what about the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @Mark: I think we're using "decidable" here in the sense of "can be proved or disproved from the axioms",

Comment: I might argue it's the other way around: the ZFC axioms were developed in hopes that they *would* decide most humanly interesting statements, and we continue to use them because they are reasonably successful in that regard.  If there were an excessive number of "interesting" undecidable statements in ZFC, we would probably by now have added more axioms to resolve them.

Comment: There is a specific diophantine equation that can be written down on a page of paper that has no solution and cannot be proved to have no solution in ZFC. I would encourage you to look into the negative result of Hilbert's Tenth Problem, from which a number of other interesting results follow (such as Richardson's Theorem). You may also be interested in Laver Tables, about which there may be a theorem requiring large cardinal axioms: https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/05/06/shelves-and-the-infinite/

Comment: I suggest you look into the [Paris-Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris–Harrington_theorem) for a natural statement that can be formulated but not proved in PA. Harvey Friedman and others have done a great deal of work in finding natural problems that are provable, but not in ZFC or interesting subsystems thereof. You can find manuscripts of Friedman's work on this [here](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/foundational-adventures/downloadable-manuscripts/).

Comment: @NateEldredge I think, though, that there's still a surprising feature here: the ZFC axioms are relatively easy to motivate. If the mathematical community found certain extremely complicated Diophantine equations particularly interesting for whatever reason, I'm not sure there would be a "natural" set of axioms which would decide them. So there's still something arguably surprising here: that there is a natural(ish) axiom system which seems to decide "most" statements we care about.